# Create local svn repo / URL?

Tags: svn

I need an SVN repo, just local on my PC. What I did was

```
mkdir ~/svn/MyProject
svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs ~/svn/MyProject
svnserve -d
```

Under `~/svn/MyProject`, there's a conf folder, so I take it that creating the repo was successful.

I would expect the repo to be accessible under `svn://127.0.0.1/svn/MyProject` but it isn't. Are there other steps that I need to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to note:

If you starting `svnserve` without rooting to parent of repo-collection (-r parameter), URL in path-part must contain **full path** from the *root of filesystem* to the repo-folder, like

`svn://127.0.0.1/home/user/svn/MyProject`

Answer (score 0):

Just found out it is reachable with this URL: file:///home/myUsername/svn/MyProject. Enough if only used locally.